# Crystal Reports Display Records in different pages

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I Have created a Cristal report that contains details about the job the details contains in the page header consist of job no ,job name...

I want display the report in different page when the job no changes

the idea is that all the jobs having the same jobno should display in one page and if the jobno changes at the middle of one page then the details about that job should display on other page not in the same page

Comment: Can you provide some source code of what you have done till now!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a group on jobno; set group to 'repeat group header on each page'.  Add desired fields to group header.  Suppress group footer; set 'force new page after' in group footer.

Answer (score 0):

I checked *Keep together* option in group expert options ... Problem Solved